# Nagios - Service checks for all but notify in work hours for some

Tags: nagios

I have a group of machines all running the same checks.

Within this group there are dev machines and prod machines.

I only want to be alerted to the checks after hours when the machines are prod machines.

With the minimum amount of changes what is the simplest way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on how you configure it. Service notification time inherits from host notification time, and you can make hosts use a template. That's how I tend to set up these things.

Comment: I found this - http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objectinheritance.html so I think I'll use the host template. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to work with Nagios, but wouldn't it be better if you grouped your hosts by "prod" and "dev" machines instead of "same checks" machines? That way you could set one notification rule for the whole group instead of doing it individually.

I know that you can define multiple groups for a host in Zabbix but I don't know if that would work in Nagios.